# delete selected rows from gridview on selecting option from a dropdownlist located outside the gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a dropdownlist and a gridview control. DropDownlist is outside the gridview.
Dropdownlist contains an option Delete.
Gridview contains checkbox so that rows can be selected.

here is the gridview code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvRefDetail" runat="server" CssClass="mGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                        PageSize="50" Font-Names="Segoe UI" Font-Size="10pt" Width="800" AllowPaging="true"
                        BackColor="White" BorderColor="Silver" EmptyDataText="No Record" BorderStyle="Double"
                        BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4">
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="red" />
                        <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#003399" />
                        <Columns>

                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                <HeaderTemplate>
                                    <input id="Checkbox2" type="checkbox" onclick="CheckAll(this)" runat="server" /></HeaderTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="NameofReferred">
                                <ItemStyle Wrap="true" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lbltext" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("NameofReferred") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txttext" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("NameofReferred")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CustomerName">
                                <ItemStyle Wrap="true" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lbltext" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("CustomerName") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txttext" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("CustomerName")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#006699" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCFFFF" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#009999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#CCFF99" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="White" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Gray" BorderColor="Gray" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#009999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#CCFF99" />
                        <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    </asp:GridView>
```

c# code:

```
protected void ddlaction_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (ddlaction.SelectedValue == "1")
    {

        GridViewRow gvrow = gvRefDetail.SelectedRow;
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(gvrow.Cells[1].Text);
        string delref = "delete from tbl_Refferal where ID='" + id + "'  ";
        con = new SqlConnection(conString);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(delref, con);
        int temp1 = cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        BindRef();

    }

    }
```

Now, my question is when I select a one or more rows from gridview and select the delete option from dropdownlist, the selected rows must get deleted.

How can I do this?

Comment: what you tried so far ?. ServerSide Code Pls so we can answer easily n in better way. Well all you need to fetch checkbox selected values and on `dropdownlist_selectedindex` change if its ur `delete` item selected then fire `delete` queries (for checkbox values selected)

Comment: @Satindersingh-I have added c# code.Please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code On `ddlaction_SelectedIndexChanged` and `stringVariableContainCheckboxvalues` is string variable fetch from gridview checkbox selected  in format `('1,3,5,6')`

```
if (ddlaction.SelectedValue == "1")
{
  string delref = "delete from tbl_Refferal where ID in (@checkboxSelectedValues)";
  con = new SqlConnection(conString);
  SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(delref, con);
  cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@checkboxSelectedValues", stringVariableContainCheckboxvalues);
  con.Open();
  int temp1 = cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
  con.Close();
  BindRef();
}
```

Fetch Multiple Checkbox values:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in gvRefDetail.Rows)
{
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("CheckBox1");
    if (cb != null && cb.Checked)
    {
       // fetch values in string
    }
}
```